# JAVA - Creating and showing a transparent window with a button

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I'm trying to create a transparent fullscreen overlay with a bunch of buttons.

I've used JFrame to create the overlay, however, but the button does not show.

```
package com.Flickr.firstApp;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.Random;

public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
        Robot robot = new Robot();
        Random random = new Random();

        Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Flow Layout");

        frame.setUndecorated(true);
        frame.setOpacity(0.2f);

        frame.setSize(screenSize);

        Panel panel = new Panel();
            panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,100));


            panel.setBackground(Color.MAGENTA);


            JButton b1 = new JButton("hello");
panel.add(b1);



        frame.add(panel);

        frame.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

As a newbie, there's a few questions that would help deepen my understanding:

1. Why doesn't the button show?
2. Why does the Panel cover the whole frame even though I've set the size to 200x200? Does it attempt to fill the frame by default?
3. Does content have to go in a panel or can we put buttons, etc directly onto the frame?

If you could answer any one of these questions, or point me towards a resource that can, that would be awesome. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The button shows for me. Its opacity makes it hard to see.
2. The default layout manager for the content pane of the frame is a BorderLayout. When you don't specify a constraint it is added the the `CENTER`. Any component in the CENTER is resized to fill the space available in the frame.
3. You can add any component to the frame. If you add the button directly, then it will be resized to fill the frame. You need to understand how layout managers work.

Don't use a Panel, that is an AWT component. Use a `JPanel` for Swing.

> point me towards a resource

Read the [Swing Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html) for many Swing basics. There are sections on:

1. A Visual Guide to Layout Managers
2. How to Create Translucent and Shaped Windows

Along with other basic demo programs to get you started.